# Is it possible to use destructuring in function arguments?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin supports destructuring declarations:

```
val (a, b) = Pair(1,2)
```

This is similar to Python's iterable unpacking:

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

Python also has a splat/spread operator that allows you to perform a similar operation with function arguments:

```
def f(a, b): pass
pair = (1,2)
f(*pair)
```

Does kotlin have a similar ability? Obviously, you can unpack the structure manually:

```
f(pair.component1(), pair.component2())
```

But that's clunky. Is there a way to do that more elegantly? I don't see anything in the [docs on the subject](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, this is possible only for arrays and vararg-functions

```
val foo = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val bar = arrayOf(0, *foo, 4)
```

Comment: That's too bad. Strange that the spread operator exists in such a limited fashion.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the answer by @Ivan, here are the related issues:

1) spread operator for non-vararg arguments in function calls:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6732

2) destructuring for lambda arguments:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5828

You can vote for them.

---

**Update:**

Destructuring for lambda arguments was implemented in Kotlin 1.1.

Answer (score 4):

You could define an extension function to spread the arguments of the `Pair`. Like this:

```
fun <A, B, R> Pair<A, B>.spread(f: (A, B) -> R) = f(first, second)

fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(Pair(1, 2).spread(::add))
}
```

This prints 3.

Comment: `fun <A, B, R> ((A, B) -> R).spread(p:Pair<A, B>) = invoke(p.first, p.second)` to pass function which take single pair arg, but actualy two `::myFunc::spread`